# Getting the location of the `.bat` file from within it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a `.bat` script for Windows. Is there any command that I can use within the script to retrieve the directory that the script is in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from : http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html

In a batch file to display the location of the batch script file (%0)

> ECHO "%~dp0"

Answer (score -1):

echo %CD%

should work

Comment: I didn't ask for the current directory, I asked for the directory that the script is in.

Comment: aw, was assuming you ran the script from the same directory

Comment: That's not always a valid assumption :-)